# using directive in angularjs for getting filepath

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, filepath

I am creating a web app in angularjs but i am not very familiar with directives in angularjs

i want to get the file path of the selected file by a particular user

```
<script>
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',  function($scope, $http, $q){
    $scope.uploadFile=function(){
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    console.log(f);
    console.log(files);
    }
});

myApp.directive('customFileInput', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            scope: false,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('change', function (evt) {
                    var files = evt.target.files;
                    scope.filename = files[0].name
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

this is my script in which i used angularjs app, controller and directive

but i am not able to call the directive on the button click

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  ggggg
<input id="file" type="file" ng-model="mdfile" ng-change="filepath()" class="form-control" custom-directive custom-file-input />
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>
```

this is my button and input field with file upload

when i click on the button i am getting the following error

```
ReferenceError: files is not defined
    at b.$scope.uploadFile (image.html:22)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14539), <anonymous>:4:221)
    at b (angular.js:15628)
    at e (angular.js:25172)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:17478)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25177)
    at Rf (angular.js:3487)
    at HTMLButtonElement.d (angular.js:3475)
```

what i need to do if i want to get the file path and use this directive?

Comment: Can you try `var files = element[0].files;`?

Comment: understand before you are commenting something sir

Comment: `files` is not a scope variable not it is defined.

Comment: how can i get the file path?

Comment: `files` is not defined your error come from `console.log(files);`

Comment: what i need to do,


i want full path of the inserted file

Answer (score 0):

See this Plunkr:

https://embed.plnkr.co/dmNRL8bj7E5ZtnArQ0sm/

I changed your directive to make it alert the url on change

```
  app.directive('customFileInput', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: false,
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change', function (evt) {
                var files = evt.target.files;
                var filename = files[0].name;
                alert(URL.createObjectURL(files[0]));
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: So did this fix it?